# Why is $(-\Delta)^{\frac 12}$ a nonlocal operator (with spectral definition) but the ordinary Laplacian is not?

Tags: functional-analysis, laplacian

Take the Neumann Laplacian on a bounded domain $-\Delta$.

We define $(-\Delta)^{\frac 12}u = \sum_{k}\lambda_k^{\frac 12}(u,w_j)_{L^2}w_j$ where $w_j$ and $\lambda_j$ are the eigenelements when $u$ is smooth.

Using this definition (and not the other ones), how do i see that $(-\Delta)^{\frac 12}$ is a nonlocal operator?

I think the answer is: we need to compute $(u,w_j)_{L^2}$ which requires knowing what $u$ is on the whole domain. BUT the ordinary Laplacian, who is NOT nonlocal, can be defined
$$(-\Delta)u = \sum_{k}\lambda_k(u,w_j)_{L^2}w_j$$
and by the reasoning above this operator is also nonlocal, which is not right.

Comment: the only way I know is to say that $(-\Delta)^{1/2}$ is a pseudo-differential operator, but, as its principal symbol says, not a differential operator, so it is non-local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Laplacian is local because that is how we define it.
It is just a partial differential operator.
It happens to be an elliptic one, so we can define its powers in a nice way as you describe, and they are all pseudodifferential operators.
This means that they are pseudolocal; the singularities of $(-\Delta)^{1/2} u$ are where those of $u$ are but the smooth parts may move around.

Integer powers of the Laplacian also have a nice spectral representation and they are pseudodifferential operators, too, but they happen to be in fact differential operators.
In fact, a power of the Laplacian is a differential operator if and only if it is obviously so; other powers are only pseudodifferential.

Another way to see this is that the Laplacian doesn't have any preferred direction or point.
Therefore $(-\Delta)^{1/2}$ shouldn't, either.
But how could this be possible for a first order differential operator, which would have to be of the form $V\cdot\nabla$ for some vector field $V$?

Comment: Joonas thanks for your answer, but my question is more: with the spectral definition of the Laplacian I wrote in the last displayed equation in the OP, how can I tell that the Laplacian is a local operator, **forgetting about all the other ways to define the Laplacian**, just using that formula?

Comment: @ChrisAl, the problem is that the numbers $\lambda_k$ come to your formula from the Laplacian. They are the eigenvalues of this particular differential operator. If you used some other numbers instead of eigenvalues, you would probably not even have a pseudodifferential operator. The Laplacian is already deep inside your spectral definition.

Comment: Ah of course. Thank you.